# Is thermal conductivity affected by change in length at all?

Tags: conductors, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

k = (QL)/(tA(T1-T2))

where k is Thermal conductivity

and Q is thermal energy transferred

and L is length of material along which heat is transferred

and t is time taken to transfer heat

and A is cross sectional area

and T1 - T2 is temperature difference

So if the length L is doubled will it have any effect on the constant of Thermal conductivity, k?
Well no because k is a constant and the k is derived by the fact that flow rate of Q/t is directly proportional to change in temperature and cross sectional area but inversely proportional to length along which thermal energy is being transferred.

i.e. Q/t is directly proportional to (A(T1-T2))/L
and with equality sign Q/t = k(A(T1-T2))/L

so k remains constant.

But when I searched it online the answers were quite contrary to my observation.

The question is does thermal conductivity change if thickness of wall is changed.

In my opinion it does not as the nature of wall is same. Changing thickness i.e. L in the formula will not change k.

But here are some contrasting answers:

> What happens to the thermal conductivity of a wall if its thickness is doubled?
>
> (A) becomes double
>
> (B) remains the same
>
> (C) becomes half
>
> (D) becomes one fourth
>
> Answer: (A) becomes double

Following is the link of the site.

https://sheir.org/quiz/what-happens-to-the-thermal-conductivity-of-a-wall-if-its-thickness-is-doubled/

So Please confirm if I am correct and if otherwise, explain.

Comment: Conductivity is intrinsic property, maybe your meant thermal conductance

Comment: You mean the website is referring to conductance. @Mauricio